# CSS overflow:visible (on hover) moves buttons to match text

Tags: css, button, hover, overflow, navbar

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ8wa.png)

I have a question about setting an element to overflow:visible when hovered over.

I have a set of buttons, each with an icon and some #text. Using CSS only, I would like to have the button display only the icon. But when I hover over it, I'd like to see the #text below the button. The solution I came up with for this is to set the button size to the same as the img size. Then, under button:hover I added an overflow: visible. This way, the text is visible when I hover over it. So far so good.

This works for a single button that's next to other buttons that have no #text in them. However, when this button is next to another button with #text that I wish to repeat this to, the bottoms of the buttons in the same area also shift down to the bottom of the text.

Here is the CSS I'm using:

```css
#navbar-left button, #navbar-middle button, #navbar-right button {
    min-height: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    margin: 0 1vw 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navbar-left button {
    float: left
}
#logout-button {
    float: right;
    direction: rtl;
}
#navbar button, #navbar button img {
    font-size: 0;
    height: 6vh;
    width: 6vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#navbar button:hover {
    font-size: 2vh;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

I screwed around with margins quite a bit, but that doesn't seem to fix it. The #logout-button seems to function fine.

My question is, how do I make the buttons stay at their intended position, rather than moving to the bottom of another button's #text?

Here is the html pulled from an inspector:

```
<div id="app"><nav id="navbar"><div id="navbar-left"><button id="chat-button"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
  Join the Discord chat
</button> <br class="hide-1280"> <button><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></button> <button><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></button></div> <div id="navbar-middle"><!----> <button><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAuUlEQVRYhe3W0Q2CMBRGYUZgBEfoCI7iSI7gCI7ACG6iGxxfSkRyW0r5b3i5N+lb0/MlEOgwxHQOcAfSWfEH8MlLiwCu/M9UiCfgJkfUAEZcjzAAz0Ic4C1HrAAvYCzEcUEsAC1xPSID9sS1CODSEZcjeuIaxMH4MYQo3ocQx/chnOJtCOf4NoLfNz05xeeZlj3rMaz/AS6A2ksYgOpFxGtfAAKgOLh1AhCATcCYD5+XeXkw9rUu87wvKiRmOIYzk1AAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
      Home
    </button> <button><img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
      Duel Zone
    </button> <button><img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
      Deck Editor
    </button> <button><img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
      Settings
    </button></div> <div id="navbar-right"><button id="logout-button"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
  Logout (Yubelious)
</button></div></nav> <div id="socket-connection"><p><span class="dot success"></span> Connected to the lobby</p> <!----> <!----> <!----></div> <div><div id="adsense"><ins data-ad-client="ca-pub-5258574472184148" data-ad-slot="7225395004" class="adsbygoogle" style="display: inline-block; width: 728px; height: 90px;" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_0_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:90px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:728px;background-color:transparent;"><ins id="aswift_0_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:90px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:728px;background-color:transparent;"><iframe width="728" height="90" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_0" name="aswift_0" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;border:0px;width:728px;height:90px;"></iframe></ins></ins></ins></div> <!----> <article id="home-area"><h2>Dueling Nexus</h2> <p>Welcome back, Yubelious.</p> <p><button><img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

Comment: I would try something different from `overflow`. Instead, maybe use `opacity`, and wrap your button text in a div with a class. The code could look something like this: `button .label { opacity: 0; } button:hover .label { opacity: 1; }`

Comment: Aren't .labels an HTML thing? If so, I would be unable to add a .label, as I don't have access to the HTML. Would an ::after work instead?
I'm trying overflow because the #text is attached to the img, and can't be coded specifically (font-size etc is determined by button, for example). The idea of using overflow is to not push the other buttons to the right with an animation. This isn't a problem for the right-most button of this set, but for anything left of that, making a button grow out left or right isn't an option. The #text must come out the bottom, without shifting the other buttons.

Comment: Can you post the HTML? I'm unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added the html to the original post. It's on the website https://duelingnexus.com/, if that helps. I'm trying to adapt it to a width under 1250px (If you're familiar with @media). So you'll get the effect I'm trying to avoid at around 1024×768 resolution or less (I like 800×600 for testing this).

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top;` to your `#navbar button` CSS.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.